# COUNT always returning 1

Tags: php, sql

I have issue where `obj->num_rows` constantly returns `1` Heres my code:

```
$open_tickets = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM support_tickets WHERE Username='" . $_SESSION['user'] . "'");
    echo '<table><tr><th>Open Tickets</th><td>' . $open_tickets->num_rows . '</td></tr></table>';
$open_tickets->close();
```

`$_SESSION['user']` is currently `dextermb`

[image: Image of SQL Table]

As you can see in my SQL table, there are **2 tickets with the name dextermb**, so why does the code always return `1`?

Comment: You are looking at `num_rows` rather than the value returned by the query.  An aggregation query with no `group by` always returns only one row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - even if I add `GROUP BY Username` on the end of the query it still returns `1`

Comment: That's because the usernames are the same

Comment: `COUNT(*)` is the value you are looking for. The value from the query is `2` but you are counting the number of values which is `1`, do you get the difference? Alternative changing your query to `SELECT * FROM` and then with `$open_tickets->num_rows` will give you 2.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger - That worked! Thanks for the help, submit an answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the number of rows returned - of course, this is only ever going to be 1. You probably want to get the value that is returned rather than the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $open_tickets = $con->query("SELECT * FROM support_tickets WHERE Username='" .                        $_SESSION['user'] . "'");
 echo '<table><tr><th>Open Tickets</th><td>' . count($open_tickets) . '</td></tr>   </table>';
  $open_tickets->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The query will return the count, just use the value.

Try:

```
$open_tickets = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM support_tickets WHERE Username='" . $_SESSION['user'] . "'");
echo '<table><tr><th>Open Tickets</th><td>' . $open_tickets . '</td></tr></table>';
```

$open_tickets->close();

Comment: I get the error: `Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string`

Comment: Ok, try this: `$open_tickets = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM support_tickets WHERE Username='" . $_SESSION['user'] . "'");
echo '<table><tr><th>Open Tickets</th><td>' . $open_tickets['count'] . '</td></tr></table>';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$stm = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM support_tickets WHERE Username = :username");
$stm->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION['user']);
$stm->execute();
$row = $res->fetch();
echo '<table><tr><th>Open Tickets</th><td>' . $row->total . '</td></tr></table>';
```

Note prepare and bindParam methods. This way you avoid SQL Injection.